# Able to access object returned by service, but accessing its properties gives undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory, angularjs-http

I'm an angular beginner and I'm trying to set up a factory that gets data from my php back-end and updates the controller.  Here is my basic code:

**factory**

```
app.factory('sessionStatus', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
        status:function(){
            var status = {};
            $http.get('/game_on/api/api.php?session-status')
            .then(function(response){
                angular.copy(response.data, status);
            });
            return status;
        }
    };
}]);
```

**controller**

```
app.controller('headerCtrl', ['$scope', 'sessionStatus', function($scope, sessionStatus){

    $scope.sessionStatus = sessionStatus.status();

    console.log($scope.sessionStatus);

}]);
```

This gives me the following in the console:

```
Object{}
  session:"false"
```

However, when I adjust the controller to log the value of the session property like so:

```
console.log($scope.sessionStatus.session);
```

I simply get undefined in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

For anyone else who suffers from my distinct brand of retardation, here's the conclusion I've reached:

The main cause of the issue is that I've been trying to access asynchronously generated information returned by the $http service before its promise has been resolved (i.e. before `.then()` is finished executing), which is leading to undefined being logged because the data has literally not yet been defined since the request that generates it is still in progress by the time `console.log()` is called in the controller.

Using the $timeout service I was able to delay the calling of `console.log()`, which resulted in the data being correctly logged to the console.

```
$timeout(function(){
    console.log($scope.sessionStatus.session);
}, 2000); // logs "false" to the console like originally expected
```

My previous thinking was that I should make the call to my factory method as short as possible within the controller, and then act upon its results outside of that call.  This was obviously a bad idea because `.then()` exists so that you can act on the results of an asynchronous request at the precise moment the request is completed.

In hindsight this all seems so obvious, but hopefully this explanation helps someone else in the future...

Thanks for all the answers I received, they were a big help!

Comment: console.log is an asynchronous action and doesn't always log the value at the exact time you would expect it to. In your controller, if your change `console.log($scope.sessionStatus);` to `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.sessionStatus));`, what does it output then?

Edit: I suspect your console.log is completing before the promise is being return, which is why you cannot access the property.

Comment: @IthinkIcancode - Yes, it seems you are correct.  JSON.stringify() outputs an empty object.

Comment: @IthinkIcancode - I was able to log the desired value by using $timeout to set a 2 second delay on the console.log call, so it seems to definitely be caused by asynchronicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since javascript is asynchronous it does't wait until http response and return the status. thats  why it return null. try something like this

```
   app.factory('sessionStatus', ['$http', function($http){
            return {
                status:function(){
                 $http.get('/game_on/api/api.php?session-status')
                }
            };
        }]);

        app.controller('headerCtrl', ['$scope', 'sessionStatus', function($scope, sessionStatus){

            $scope.sessionStatus = sessionStatus.status().then(function(response) { 
               console.log(response);
        });


    }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of changes that you can make to the code here. First I would suggest resolving the promise and assigning the value in the controller instead of in the service. Next, you won't need to use Angular.Copy on the result object, you can simply make a variable assignment. Try something like simply this, then build out:

```
app.factory('sessionStatus', ['$http', function($http){

    return {status: $http.get('/game_on/api/api.php?session-status')}

}]);
```

and

```
app.controller('headerCtrl', ['$scope', 'sessionStatus', function($scope, sessionStatus){

    sessionStatus.status.then(function(result){
        $scope.sessionStatus = result.data; //or some property on result
    });

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I've tried this as a solution before, but was unable to access the value of the assigned $scope variable outside of the promise's then method.  As noted in my comment on the OP this seems to be because of async, which is fine, but can you tell me if it is practically possible to access these values outside of the then method, or if it is simply a requirement that all code that relies on such values be located within it so that it will run only once the promise has been returned?  Thanks.

Comment: You're always going to have to have code in the return method. Now that being said, you can find some creative ways to make that work with your application. What it comes down to most of the time is how you have decided to architect your application, so that promises properly update your values, instead of get in the way. I put together a fiddle to show some examples. [check it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/kg6qevh0/). Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try to return a promise from your `factory`:

```
app.factory('sessionStatus', ['$http', function($http) {
  var factory = {
    status: status
  };

  return factory;

  function status() {
    return $http.get('/game_on/api/api.php?session-status');
  }
}]);
```

Then in **controller**:

```
app.controller('headerCtrl', ['$scope', 'sessionStatus', function($scope, sessionStatus) {
  function getSuccess(response) {
    $scope.sessionStstus = response.data;
  }

  function getError(response) {
    console.log('error');
  }

  sessionStatus.status()
    .then(getSuccess)
    .catch(getError);

  console.log($scope.sessionStatus);
}]);
```